# Alert box on click out side of text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 text box fields and submit button( name, description and submit).
I fill up title field. and using tab key or using mouse focus i focus on description field.
At that time i get alert box. Using following code.

```
var blurTimeout;

function cancelBlur(){
    clearTimeout(blurTimeout);
}

$("input[name=category_name]").live("blur", function() {
         blurTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            alert("Click 'Save Changes' button to save category.");
        }, 200);

});
```

But now i want that once i fill up name and then click on description then no alert should display. But after filling up description field once i click out side of this 2 text boxs alert should display.

html for button:

```
<div class="select-btn">
  <button class="button btn" TYPE="submit" onclick="cancelBlur();">
  <span>Save Changes</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: i don;t see you execute event click...?

Comment: Where is your onclick???

Comment: It is a blur alert not an onclick so there is not meant to be a click event

Comment: on click is on submit button.<div class="select-btn"><button class="button btn" TYPE="submit" onclick="cancelBlur();"><span><span>Save Changes</span></span></button></div>

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change it to:

```
$("input[name=description]").live("blur", function() {
     blurTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        alert("Click 'Save Changes' button to save category.");
    }, 200);
});
```

Or if you want to make sure that both are filled out before you send the alert:

```
$("input[name=category_name], input[name=description]").live("blur", function() {
  if($("input[name=category_name]").val() && $("input[name=description]").val()){   
    blurTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        alert("Click 'Save Changes' button to save category.");
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

Attach the blur event to both fields in case they fill out the form backwards, and check that the form is filled out each time.  If it is all filled out, give them the alert. .. there might be typos, im sleepy

Comment: Thnx jeff. 2nd Solution is working perfect for me. Appriciate your help.